# C++ static property initialization error on string

Tags: c++, qt, class, static-methods

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <QString>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    static const int i = 9;
    static const int PI = 1.3;
    static const char ch = 's';
    static const string str = "hello world"; // <--- error
    static const QString str2 = "hello world"; // <--- error
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    cout << "Hello world" << endl;

    return 0 ;
}
```

As the code gives everything, how can I init a string.

Comment: The question has been answered, but just for the next time: say what error get exactly.

Comment: @MrLister it's working fine now. But I wonder how const can be declared later!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Non-integral type members (that includes `string` and your user-defined types), need to be initialized outside the class definition, in a single implementation file (`.cc` or `.cpp` usually).

In your case, since you didn't separate the class definition in a header, you can initialize the `static`s right after your class:

```
class A {
public:
    static const int i = 9;
    static const int PI = 1.3;
    static const char ch = 's';
    static const string str;
    static const QString str2;
};


const string A::str = "hello world";
const QString A::str2 = "hello world";
```

EDIT: Besides this, as Nawaz pointed out, the header file that defines `string` is `<string>`, not `<cstring>`.

Comment: It's not "user-defined members". In C++03 it's "non-integral types", and in C++11 its anything that doesn't have a constant-expression initialization.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Actually, to be precise only *static const integers & enums* can have In-Class Initialization in C++03.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: `char` *is* an integral type.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: `char` is an integral-type (I think, *integer* is a misleading term). Try `float` or `double`, they will not compile.

Comment: @KerrekSB I know, but Als said integers. I'm guessing he meant integral types, not ints. :)

Comment: @Nawaz I know, but Als' comment was "static const integers".

Comment: Yes, I meant Integral constants, For sake of completeness, **C++03 9.4.2 Static data members:** *"If a static data member is of const integral or const enumeration type, its declaration in the class definition can specify a constant-initializer which shall be an integral constant expression (5.19). In that case, the member can appear in integral constant expressions. The member shall still be defined in a namespace scope if it is used in the program and the namespace scope definition shall not contain an initializer."*

Comment: @Luchian Grigore It's working fine. But it's little obfuscate to me how can a **const**-tagged item can be declared further. But as Nawaz told C++11 has a better syntax I guess.

Comment: @Dewsworld you can declare a const as many times as you want. But this is a one-time definition. What you have in a class is just a declaration, what's outside is the initialization.

Comment: @Nawaz I tried float and double and both are working fine actually !!

Answer (score 3):

- First thing first. You've not included `<string>`. So do that first:

  ```
  #include <string>
  ```

  `std::string` is defined in `<string>`, not in `<cstring>` as you probably might think.
- After that in C++03, initialization of the non-integral static member of a class, must be outside the class.
- In C++11,  your code will compile if you only include `<string>`. No need to define the static member outside the class.

Comment: +1 so in C++11 you can initialize any statics in the class definition?

Comment: @Nawaz Thanks it's working. But I doubt what is **<cstring>** then? Becuase I thougt it is somewhat *modern* string version!!

Comment: @Dewsworld: `<cstring>` (in C++) contains what `<string.h>` (in C) contains. `<cstring>` is just add namespace to all the members found in `<string.h>`. For example, in C you use `strlen()` which is defined in `<string.h>`; in C++ you use `std::strlen()` which is defined in `<cstring>`